# Rails - Override all type of setter for a field in a Mongoid Document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, overriding, mongoid, setter

i'm working in a group project using rails as languaje and mongo as database. I want to store in the db string data in lowercase, like the fields name, lastname, description, etc. So i overrode the some setters using this syntax:

```
def name=(attr_value)
  super(attr_value.downcase)
end
```

That worked fine, because ODM methods like new, create, update do the job, and when i set the attribute using dot syntax, works fine:

```
product = Product.new(name:'Jesus')
puts product.name // Show jesus
product.name = 'Tom'
puts product.name // Show tom
```

But when i tried to assign the value using the model as hash, the setter is not called:

```
product[:name] = 'Chris'
puts product.name // Show Chris
product['name'] = 'Charles'
puts product.name // Show Charles
```

Because i heavily use that notation and great part of the actual project use that syntax, i really want to know if there a method per attribute which i can override to approach all the cases that i showed. Thanks for your help.

**P.D.** I already check the methods `[]=(attr_name,attr_value)` and `write_attribute(attr_name,attr_value)`, but these methods are called when any of the attributes of the model is assigned a value using, and i really don't want to use complex logic inside of the setter to determine which attributes edit and which not.

Comment: You would be better off going with a `before_save` or `before_validation` [callback](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-callbacks/) then you can just adjust the attributes prior to persistence. This avoids any concern for the setter method utilized and avoids the need to try and patch over all of these methods independently

Comment: Try https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-documents/#custom-fields.

Comment: @engineersmnky i liked that option, so i implemented it and worked fine, but my group doesn't liked so much, so i'm gonna wait for another solution for a moment.

Comment: @D.SM i see the potencial for the custom fields, but i'm kinda stuck for how to implement it in my model, principally for the fact of that almost all my fields are String, not custom clases, and because i want to modify some fields, so i'm not sure how affect edit those 3 methods on the other fields from the model.